# Angular 5 material new palette not compiling

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular5, angular-material2

I'm trying to generate a new material theme with a custom palette for the primary color, the scss code is below:

```html
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$potti-brown: (
    50: #fcf2e7,
    100: #f8dec3,
    200: #f3c89c,
    300: #eeb274,
    400: #eaa256,
    500: #e69138,
    600: #e38932,
    700: #df7e2b,
    800: #db7424,
    900: #d56217,
    A100: #ffffff,
    A200: #ffe3d4,
    A400: #ffc3a1,
    A700: #ffb287,
    contrastDefaultColor: light,
    contrastDarkColors: (
      50,
      100,
      200,
      300,
      400,
      500,
      600,
      700,
      800,
      A100,
      A200,
      A400,
      A700
    ),
    contrastLightColors: (
      900
    )
);

$potti-primary: mat-palette($potti-brown);
$potti-accent:  mat-palette($mat-lime, 100);
$potti-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$potti-theme: mat-light-theme($potti-primary, $potti-accent, $potti-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($potti-theme);
```

I've followed the tutorials on angular.io, but when I try to ng serve, I get the following error:

```html
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles/app.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Backtrace:
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `map-get`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `mat-contrast`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1129, in function `mat-palette`
        src/styles/pottiTheme.scss:40
      in E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1114, column 11)
Error:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Backtrace:
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `map-get`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `mat-contrast`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1129, in function `mat-palette`
        src/styles/pottiTheme.scss:40
      in E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1114, column 11)
    at options.error (E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
 @ ./src/styles/app.scss 4:14-197
 @ multi ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./src/styles/app.scss ./src/styles/pottiTheme.scss ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles/pottiTheme.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Backtrace:
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `map-get`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `mat-contrast`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1129, in function `mat-palette`
        stdin:40
      in E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1114, column 11)
Error:
undefined
         ^
      Argument `$map` of `map-get($map, $key)` must be a map

Backtrace:
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `map-get`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1114, in function `mat-contrast`
        node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss:1129, in function `mat-palette`
        stdin:40
      in E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss (line 1114, column 11)
    at options.error (E:\potti2\pottiRoma-master\pottiRoma-master\PottiRoma\AdminWebPottiRoma\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
 @ ./src/styles/pottiTheme.scss 4:14-204
 @ multi ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./src/styles/app.scss ./src/styles/pottiTheme.scss ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css
```

The compilation process works if instead of using the custom palette I use a standart angular material palette like $mat-lime.

Can someone point it out to me where I'm getting this wrong? I'm sure it's a stupid little thing that I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT SOLVED:**

@yurzui helped me out with the $mat-lime source code and I just adapted the colors to the ones on my palette and it worked fine! There must have been some syntax error since i used an angular 2 theme generator. The correct code is below:

```html
$potti-brown: (
  50: #fcf2e7,
  100: #f8dec3,
  200: #f3c89c,
  300: #eeb274,
  400: #eaa256,
  500: #e69138,
  600: #e38932,
  700: #df7e2b,
  800: #db7424,
  900: #d56217,
  A100: #ffffff,
  A200: #ffe3d4,
  A400: #ffc3a1,
  A700: #ffb287,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $dark-primary-text,
    600: $dark-primary-text,
    700: $dark-primary-text,
    800: $dark-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $dark-primary-text,
    A400: $dark-primary-text,
    A700: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);
```

Comment: Did you check the backtrace? Looks like angular material module issue? Can you try to update or reinstall the module?

Comment: Have you tried using the same keys that `$mat-lime` uses? https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/a943b36c7b308019f89f3482d047f17ecfb33caa/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss#L402-L433

Comment: @wannadream it is not an angular material issue, the rest of the module is working perfectly, its in the stack trace because the compilation of the rest of it failed from that point on.

Comment: @yurzui when i used the $mat-lime keys and replaced it with my colors it worked! thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you update definition of your theme?

Comment: Are you sure you use the latest material version? It works for `@angular/material@5.2.3`

Comment: @yurzui when i used the $mat-lime code and changed to use my colors it worked fine!

Comment: Glad to hear you managed