# Change the Primary Color

Tags: angular-material

I have created a simple theme but I want to change the primary and secondary colors.

theme.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// #EB3D53
// #4980b3

$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey); <-- this should be #4980b3
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, 500, 900, A100);
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);
```

Attempting to pass in my color causes a compiler error. I attempted to create my own variable with my color and pass that in and that didn't work. I'm very new with SASS so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit:

I used a tool to generate the code that is not working: http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%234980b3

I used the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086881/angular-5-material-new-palette-not-compiling) which worked. I then modified it to use my colors like so:

```
$vender-portal-blue: (
50: #e9f0f6,
100: #c8d9e8,
200: #a4c0d9,
300: #80a6ca,
400: #6493be,
500: #4980b3,
600: #4278ac,
700: #396da3,
800: #31639a,
900: #21508b,
A100: #c8dfff,
A200: #95c1ff,
A400: #62a4ff,
A700: #4895ff,
contrast: (
  50: $dark-primary-text,
  100: $dark-primary-text,
  200: $dark-primary-text,
  300: $dark-primary-text,
  400: $dark-primary-text,
  500: $dark-primary-text,
  600: $dark-primary-text,
  700: $dark-primary-text,
  800: $dark-primary-text,
  900: $light-primary-text,
  A100: $dark-primary-text,
  A200: $dark-primary-text,
  A400: $dark-primary-text,
  A700: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);
```

The tool I used generated a lot of other properties which was causing the compiler to complain. I understand why it would generate this extra fluff if it's not compatible. Here's what it looked like:

```
'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
  'contrastDarkColors': [
    '50',
    '100',
    '200',
    '300',
    '400',
    'A100',
    'A200',
    'A400',
    'A700'
  ],
  'contrastLightColors': [
    '500',
    '600',
    '700',
    '800',
    '900'
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to select Angular Js 2 Material 2 as the export option.